# .htaccess for Wordpress site hacked

Tags: .htaccess

Can some kind person please help look at this .htaccess file and tell me what is the vulnerability here.. this is the .htaccess file from my Wordpress site after the hacker got in (I inherited the website so wasn't sure what it was before alternative I could revert back to reinstall Wordpress but this doesn't solve my problem).. there is a hole and these hackers keeps coming back!!!
It maybe that they have modified the Wordpress .htaccess file giving them the back door.. and also use the .htaccess to show the details of the url.. Please assists to look at this .htaccess and advise me how to fix the hole. Thank you in advanced.

```
# Enable HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_NR_SSL} !="1"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

This is a team of hackers that keeps coming back to re-direct information to their email box, despite removing the Wordpress WP-Admin page to somewhere they still managed to changed my admin password. At first I changed the admin login password hoping they go away but they still managed to look it up and changed the password, I change it back and they change it over again. I have added a login notifier plugin which worked in the beginning but now the hacker has modified something and I don't receive notification anymore on login attempts. I have added SSL but that didn't help. I have been pulling my hair!

If this helps..I think this may be the original installed of .htaccess (from USB drive of installed files)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress
```

and this is the hack version currently in Wordpress

```
# Enable HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_NR_SSL} !="1"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Understanding the criticality of .htaccess 
I am afraid to remove codes I am nt familiar with and cause the whole Wordpress site to fall over and not work again or any implications.

Comment: There doesn't look to be anything obviously malicious in the `.htaccess` file. It's likely that the hackers got in due to a vulnerability in your version of Wordpress or one of its plugins. I'd recommend updating Wordpress and all the plugins but if the problem still occurs then you'll need to do a much deeper investigation of how they're still getting in.

Comment: The .htaccess file is clean, the problem is somewhere else.